# Have multiple arguments in CommandLine (Windows Terminal)

Tags: windows-terminal

I would like to setup my profile in **Windows Terminal** in a way that it automatically connects to **server1** via ssh and using server1 it connects to **server2**.

Everything works fine when i connect to single server1 machine but not sure how to launch second command.

- What i have is:

in settings.json->"profiles"->"list" -
"commandline": "ssh -i "mykey.pem" ubuntu@server1"

- What i want to do is something like (Bellow is just for visualization, any way that gets the job done is fine)

"commandline": "ssh -i "mykey.pem" ubuntu@server1 && ssh -i "mykey.pem" ubuntu@server2"

Comment: Have you tried launching a batch file instead?  Powershell Script? ... that is the route I would lean toward.

Comment: You mean to create batch file with ssh -i "mykey.pem" ubuntu@server1 && ssh -i "mykey.pem" ubuntu@server2 and run it using commandline parameter ?

Comment: sure :) thats EXACTLY what I mean.  I don't know if you can do it or not but it is the first thing that comes to my mind.  Sure is a lot easier to lay out your calls to rather than needing to do thing1 && thing2 || thing3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found Solution thanks to https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/41493/how-to-ssh-to-a-server-using-another-server

```
ssh -t $SERVER_A ssh $SERVER_B
```

gets the job done